# Is there a difference in search engine ranking between allowing HTTPS vs requiring it?

Tags: seo, https

This is a general question, not related to google only, but for example google mentioned that it will have more trust for sites that support HTTPS and they will get a small ranking boost. I would like to dig into "support HTTPS" part.

Is it that the page is accessible via HTTPS? or is it that the page is accessible ONLY via HTTPS that is when google trusts a site more?

Answer (score 1):

When the HTTPS page appears in the Google index, they give it a boost.

When both are available Google has recently started preferring the HTTPS version in their search index.  So when you have both available, Google prefers the HTTPS version and it gets a ranking boost.

Comment: Short, pithy, and perfect.

Comment: Yes thank you. I am aware of that google prefers (only if not already set by site admin) https version and gives it a small boost in rank. But do you also know if there is a difference between allowing HTTPS vs requiring it?

Comment: As long as allowing HTTPS gets that version of the site indexed, there is no difference from an SEO perspective.